# SharePoint 2013 REST API folder (name) only

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

How to get the REST API to load only the library folders without the elements and documents in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full correct answer:

```
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Document')/items?$select=FSObjType,BaseName";
var requestHeaders = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: function (data) 
    { 
       $.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
        var name = result.FSObjType;
        if(name == 1) {
            var namefolder = [];
            namefolder.push(result.BaseName);
        }
        $("#NameFolder").autocomplete({
       source:namefolder
           });
       });
    },
    error: function ajaxError(response) {
        alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
    }
});
```

if you need only folder name, use FSObjectType integer = 1 (folder), then BaseName (folder name) or FileRef (but this full name documents\ "Document\folder name")...))

Answer (score 1):

The following call returns items with a file type of `Folder`:

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Name of the Library')/Items?$expand=Folder&$select=Title,Folder/ServerRelativeUrl
```

SP2010 approach would be the following:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/DocLib?$filter=ContentType eq 'Folder'
```

Comment: What element to take into value (result)?

Comment: It's up to you what you wish to include. The available properties of a Folder can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_Folder. We can see that available properties are e.g. ItemCount, Name, ParentFolder and WelcomePage.